# What's the status if pr2_kinematics in electric?

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been asked to install pr2_kinematics on some of our Fedora machines, but it looks like it depends on things that have been deprecated in electric, and the electric version of the wiki page is non existent. Should I go ahead and install pr2_kinematics and its deprecated dependencies, or has its functionally been replaced elsewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29204/what%27s-the-status-if-pr2_kinematics-in-electric?/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a bug in the wiki page, but I don't see any deprecation message. pr2_kinematics is still available even in ROS Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-03-12**:
I should have been more specific. It depends on motion_planning_msgs (replaced with arm_navigation_msgs in Electric) in motion_planning_common, which is deprecated.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-12**:
I don't understand the question then.  pr2_kinematics is fine to use.  The version released in electric (0.4.2) does not depend on motion_planning_common.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-03-12**:
The problem may be that there's no electric tag of pr2_kinematics (there are tags for boxturtle through diamondback). I was using latest, but that wanted arm_navigation_msgs. I guess the right question is: what is the correct version of pr2_kinematics for electric?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-12**:
http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_kinematics/Releases